# "If" with implicit "then" question: Should a comma be used?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Consider the following phrase:

> If the fruit is an apple, it should be given to children.

Is the comma after *apple* necessary? Is it optional? Is it wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In that case, the comma is optional. According to the [Wikipedia page on *comma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#Separation_of_clauses):

> In English, a comma is generally used to separate a dependent clause from the independent clause if the dependent clause comes first: *After I brushed the cat, I lint-rollered my clothes*. (Compare *I lint-rollered my clothes after I brushed the cat*.)
>
> […]
>
> While many style guides call for
> commas, many authors omit them,
> particularly with short sentences.

The two paragraphs that I extracted from the article apply to your sentence. It’s a short sentence with a dependent clause (*if the item is an apple*) and an independent clause (*it should be given to children*), where the dependent clause comes first.

Comment: I agree that the comma is optional, but my advice would be "if in doubt, include it".