# Using `but` as a conditional limit on a clause. Also implied or omitted `if`

Tags: conditionals, archaicisms, omissibility

I wanted to communicate the following with someone:

1. > I would do this thing, if I could do it.

However, always trying to be clever and using amusing, possibly archaic grammar I wanted to type:

2. > I would, but I could.

It's not clear to me this is correct in any way. Altering this again it makes more sense, reminding me of a line Shakespeare might write.

3. > But(*if*) I could do this thing, then I would.

Is sentence three (3) grammatical, and does it make sense to most people? Does this construct with `but` meaning `if` have a name? What about sentence two (2) which seems to me like a shortened version of three (3). This [SE question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/373905/247715) offers details about implied `if`, which could be related.

Comment: Shakespeare might've written *could I do this, I would do it* in the same way that we still write *had I done this, I would've done it* or *were I able, I would be able,* but this "subjunctive inversion" or whatever it's called has nothing to do with *but*. Might you be confusing the two constructions?

Comment: You can check out how ol' Shakspur actually used the word at: http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Glossary?let=b

Comment: @Anonym you are probably correct about my confusion. Or I may have incorrectly generalized some proper constructs.

Comment: @MetaEd Following your link of Shakespeare's usages says he uses _but_ as _that_. Does the sentence "I would, that I could" make more sense than "I would, but I could"? Seems so, but how?

Comment: Open discussion is more appropriate at our [chat].

Comment: Wouldn't "but that" be more idiomatic? *I would, but that I could.*

Comment: @MetaEd *But that* means *except that.*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sound smart, and up-to-date, you could try,

> I would do it, **provided** that I could.

From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/provided?s=t)

```
provided
conjunction
1. on the condition or understanding (that); providing :
I'll go provided that the others go, too.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be concise, you could say:

> I would if I could.

If you wanted to be clever you could add:

> I would if I could, but I can't so I won't.

Comment: Even more clever, if not dated, "but I can't so I *shan't*."